# How to use terraform to get all iam_users based on tags

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

I would like to get all iam_users based on specific tags.
For example I am provisioning the users like this:

```
variable "user_data" {
  default = {
    "developer" = {
      "name" = "dev1",
      "path" = "/users/developers/",
      "tag"  = { Name = "dev1" , Role = "developer" },
    },
    "admin" = {
      "name" = "administrator",
      "path" = "/users/administrators/",
      "tag"  = { Name = "Administrator" , Role = "administrators" },
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_iam_user" "users" {
  for_each = var.user_data
  name     = each.value.name
  path     = each.value.path
  tags     = each.value.tag
}
```

So now is there a way to get all the users for example with tag: `role = "developer"`?

Comment: How are you intending to use the list of users?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for block to iterate over instances created by the aws_iam_user.users resource:

```
[ for user in aws_iam_user.users: user if user.tags.Role == "developer" ]
```